# Changing attitude of hiring manager between different rounds of interviews

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, applications

So, I had two interviews with this hiring manager, the second one being more like a panel interview.

The thing is, during the first interview, I was very comfortable during the discussion with this person. He was so nice and considerate and I was thinking that I’d be happy having this person as my manager. He also seemed very interested in my application and answered my questions enthusiastically.
Fast forward to the second interview, where it seemed like this was a different person. I noticed this when he was answering my questions. He seemed annoyed and slightly yelling (as I was taking notes of some of his answers, I’ve written one answer in all caps to emphasize/match his tone). Also, the questions I asked are typical questions to ask an employer during an interview, nothing unexpected.

I don’t know what caused his attitude the second time (could it be because this is a more advanced/serious stage of the interview process, or because after our first interview he got more interesting candidates and he’s no longer that interested in my application, or he was disappointed because he expected me to give better answers during the interview…).

In any case, my question is, if offered the position, which one of the 2 impressions I got, should I give more weight when making a decision? I guess I’m worried more about the second one, because it suggests that I may not be able to ask him questions comfortably if I work with him.

---

Edit in an attempt to make it answerable:

Is there any way for following up (in case an offer is made) that may provide more clarity as to whether this may indeed be due to a bad day or if it is his expected day-to-day behaviour?

Comment: This probably isn't answerable.  Maybe you caught him on a bad day the second round because he just got some bad news.  Maybe he was on his best behavior for the first round.  None of us can guess.  Personally, I wouldn't weight one more than the other but that's me.  You may prefer to put emphasis on avoiding the worst case scenario or on finding the best case scenario or some other metric.

Comment: I would consider other opportunities as this is just a hint of things to come. Remember there is "Presentation" and then "Reality". The reality was in the second interview.

Answer (score 4):

> I don’t know what caused his attitude the second time (could it be because this is a more advanced/serious stage of the interview process, or because after our first interview he got more interesting candidates and he’s no longer that interested in my application, or he was disappointed because he expected me to give better answers during the interview…).

Could be that he was just having a bad day. Maybe his boss yelled at him, maybe he had some drama in the house, who knows.

If this second interview was a panel interview then were there other interviewers in the room as well? If so then how did they interact?

> In any case, my question is, if offered the position, which one of the 2 impressions I got, should I give more weight when making a decision? I guess I’m worried more about the second one, because it suggests that I may not be able to ask him questions comfortably if I work with him.

I would say the second one. If he's gonna act like that in an interview then he might act that as your boss too half the time. Or he could be even worse.

People often present themselves differently around strangers. People's guard can be lowered due to stress or familiarity or whatever. I'd say the second go around was probably more authentic and that should definitely factor into your decision!

Comment: > If this second interview was a panel interview then were there other interviewers in the room as well? If so then how did they interact? 

I would say they were serious, but it didn't seem to me that they answered my questions in that same slightly agressive tone. I actually focused my post on the hiring manager because 1. I didn't expect this change of attitude compared to the first time we talked and 2. if hired, he would be my boss and it's important to get a feel of what it would be like working with him. The others don't matter that much for day-to-day work.

Answer (score 1):

As I think you understand, we can't answer why this person behaved this way, or begin to guess which of the two sides of them you saw is more genuine, or more common.

However, your edit asks whether there is any way to follow up with them, to find out. I would say: very unlikely. It would, at best, require some delicate and tactful way of asking "I noticed you were quite abrasive the second time we spoke, is that how you behave normally?"; I'm not sure how that could be achieved without risking offending someone who has (by the time you ask that question) made you a job offer that you're considering accepting. It would be a high-risk strategy, let's put it that way.

What I will say is this: interviews are a two-way street. They were judging your suitability for the role, but you were judging them as a potential employer, too. If you came away with these kinds of concerns, it may well be worth trusting your own judgement. While there may be a perfectly innocent explanation - they wanted to "test you under pressure", they'd just had some bad news and weren't able to conceal it very well, whatever - it's also quite likely that that's just how they behave. You will probably only know for sure after working with them for a while. Do you want to take that risk? Well, that's for you to decide.